# Formatting columns of an output text

Tags: linux, sed, paste

I have 3 files

file1:

```
compute-0-44
compute-0-2 
compute-0-7 
compute-0-8
```

file2:

```
0
11/29/2017 | 02:01:34
0
05/16/2018 | 08:47:56
```

file3:

```
0
963
0
459
```

When I do `paste file1 file2 file 3`, I get :

```
compute-0-44    0       0
compute-0-2     11/29/2017 | 02:01:34   963
compute-0-7     0       0
compute-0-8     05/16/2018 | 08:47:56   459
```

What I want is :

```
compute-0-44    0                       0
compute-0-2     11/29/2017 | 02:01:34   963
compute-0-7     0                       0 
compute-0-8     05/16/2018 | 08:47:56   459
```

Is it possible using paste? If there are any other alternatives like sed, that will serve the purpose too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` to replace the second tab by 3 tabs if the line doesn't contain a vertical bar:

```
paste file{1..3} | sed '/|/!s/\t/\t\t\t/2'
```

Comment: I prefer use column than sed : paste file{1..3} | column -s $'\t' -t

Answer (score 1):

Using the `pr` command:

```
$ pr -mT file{1..3} | expand
compute-0-44            0                       0
compute-0-2             11/29/2017 | 02:01:34   963
compute-0-7             0                       0
compute-0-8             05/16/2018 | 08:47:56   459
```

From `man pr`:

> ```
>    -m, --merge
>           print all files in parallel, one in each column, truncate lines,
>           but join lines of full length with -J
> ```

The pipe through `expand` converts tabs to spaces - depending on your application, you may not need that (I really only added it here to make the output look correctly formatted on this site).